# How are trigonometric ratios function of interior angles in a right angled triangle?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

How can one assume that the ratio altitude/hypotenuse is a function of angle.
For a general right-angled triangle--->Let:

Hypotenuse$=c$

Altitude$=a$

Base$=b$

and angle opposite to altitude$=x$ .

Then by Pythagoras Theorem-
  $ a^2+b^2=c^2 \qquad(1)$

and for a fixed value of angle $x$ ratio of sides is constant,therefore-
  $a/c=S$, $b/c=C$ or
  $a=cS$ , $b=cC$ putting these values in equation(1):
$$
  (cS)^2+(cC)^2=c^2 \qquad
   S^2+C^2=1 \qquad(2)
$$
Where $S$ and $C$ are some constants.
My question is that how can I relate $S$ and $C$ with angle $x$.Do I simply write sin(x)=S,cos(x)=C,which according to me is just a declaration that S is a function of x.What is the real definition and how can it be derived?

Comment: Usually, what you call perpendicular, is called altitude. Yes S and C are functions of x. That's the whole point. The only problem is that this only works when $0 \lt x^\circ \lt 90^\circ$. You need to do something else to define sine and cosine for any angle.

Comment: Usually, what we call a number and use for counting could be replaced by sticks and bones.....

Answer (score 0):

By the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Right-angled_triangle_definitions) of trigonometric functions you have:
$$
S=\frac{a}{c}=\frac{1}{\sin x}  \qquad  C=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{1}{\tan x}
$$

so you have simply proved the identity:

$$
\frac{1}{\sin^2 x}=\left(1+\frac{1}{\tan^2 x} \right) 
$$
or
$$
\mbox{cosec}^2 x=1+\mbox{cotan}^2 x
$$